# BERT NLP classification model, how to combine word embeddings

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

I am using BERT embeddings to train a classification model.

For each sentence in my training data I extract the BERT embeddings for two or more words and then use these to predict the relationship in the sentence. My data looks like this

**sentence**: "Robert is the brother of John" **class**: "FAMILY_RELATIONSHIP"

**sentence**: "Constantinople is the former name of Istanbul" **class**: "HISTORICAL_RELATIONSHIP"

**sentence**: "Stacy is the daughter of Henry and Alice" **class**: "FAMILY_RELATIONSHIP"

In the first example, I get the embeddings for **Robert** and **John**, call these h1 and h2, and concatenate these, h = concat(h1, h2), and feed h into a final dense layer to predict the class.

However, in sentence 3 I have three people (**Stacy**, **Henry** and **Alice**) so h = concat(h1, h2, h3) which will be longer than for sentence 1.

What is the best way of combining the embeddings so that I have the same length input to the final dense layer?

Does it make sense to max pool the embeddings even if some sentences have 2, 3, 4, 5 or more embeddings?

Is there any other way to pass this data to the final dense layer?

EDIT

I will try and provide some more details.

I am trying to classify the relationship encoded in a sentence. The sentence may contain two or more words of interest. I know these words in advance and I can use a mask to collect the correct word embedding from BERT.

Some pseudo code might look like this:

```
# Here I have a pretrained bert model. I pass the input for each
# sentence to bert to get the word embeddings
bert_inputs = [token_ids, token_type_ids]
seq_out = bert_layer(bert_inputs)

# for each sentence, I have a mask so that I can 
# extract the embedding for the words of interest, that I know in advance 
h1 = seq_out[h1_mask] 
h2 = seq_out[h2_mask]
h3 = seq_out[h3_mask] # if there is no third word, this is empty/zero/nothing

# however, depending on the sentence I may need to concatenate 2 embeddings,
# or 3 or 4,  etc.
dense_input = concat(h1, h2) # two words case
dense_input = concat(h1, h2, h3) # three words case

# finally I pass dense_input to a standard dense layer
# but how can I do this when the length of dense_input can vary?
pred_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n=10) # 10 classes to predict
pred_layer(dense_input) # predict class
```

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding your task or any code you may have? 
Do you want to classify the relationship between any pair of words? Or words that you choose ahead of time somehow? When you want to classify the relationship of three or more words, do you want to assign a single class for all of them?

Comment: Yakov Dan, does the edit make it any clearer?

Comment: Is there a maximum to concat? You could always have a PAD/NULL value to concat to have all relationships reach the max. It's also possible that you can extract the `(h1, h2), (h1, h3)` and gather each individual relationship that way.

Comment: Have you considered using a recurrent layer, such as [LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM)? It seems suitable for this kind of a problem.